# Find shortest array count in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multidimensional array:

```
$arr = array(
    array('lions', 'tigers', 'bears'), // count = 3
    array('dogs', 'cats'), // count = 2
    array('horses', 'pigs', 'cattle', 'sheep', 'chickens') // count = 5
);
```

I want to return the array with the lowest count (I don't need to know the count, just need the array that HAS the lowest count).  In this case, `array('dogs', 'cats')`

Right now I have:

```
$lowest = null;

foreach($nodePath as $arr)
{
    $lowest = count($arr) < count($lowest) || $lowest == null ? $arr : $lowest;
}
```

This works but I'm wondering if I missed a more contained solution, perhaps using `array_map`, `array_walk` or a similar function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with `count` as a callback to get the number of elements in each array, [`min()`](http://php.net/min) to get the smallest value. Then, to get the key of the smallest array - use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/array_flip) to flip the arrays keys and values, and access the `$min`th index. Now you can use the key to get the array you need:

```
$counts = array_map('count', $arr);
$min = min($counts);
$key = array_flip($counts)[$min];
$smallest_arr = $arr[$key];
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/102717)

Answer (score 2):

Map your array to another array with counts of each child array. Get the key of the minimum value in this new array. Smallest array has the key of the minimum value:

```
$count = array_map('count', $arr);
$min = array_keys($count , min($count))[0];

var_dump($arr[$min]); // Array ( [0] => dogs [1] => cats )
```

[**Eval.in**](https://eval.in/102719)